# Content Security Policy: allow only my S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, content-security-policy

In our site we want fonts only from our sources. Here is the policy:

```
Content-Security-Policy: font-src fonts.gstatic.com https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/* https://*.mysite.com:*
```

By introducing "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/*" I was assuming it allows fonts from our bucket. However I see the following error in browser console:

```
Refused to load the font 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src fonts.gstatic.com https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/* https://*.mysite.com:*".
```

Can anyone help me to add my bucket name as font source in CSP header? Thanks!

Comment: I could add 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com' instead of 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket//*' but font sources on UI is managed by other team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Content Security Policy is not support the wildcard `*` in the path-part, see [match-paths spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-paths).
Instead of `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/*` you can use `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/` that means the same - any files or any subfolders nested into `/mybucket/`.

BTW, `https://*.mysite.com:*` allows fonts loading only from subdomains of `mysite.com`, but not from `mysite.com` itself.
The `:*` means any port number, but `https:` uses 443 port by default, so you can just use `https://*.mysite.com`.